# Sql Nested query with MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 4 columns

For every id on Col2 and for every value=c on Col1, I need to update Column DataNew with the most recent date (from Column Data) found on the record that has that same ID and a value of either a and b on Col1

Here is an example with DataNew after the update.

```
Col1|Col2|Data      |DataNew
----|----|----------|-----------
a   |x   |12/05/2013|
b   |x   |12/04/2013|
c   |x   |12/09/2013|12/04/2013
b   |x   |12/08/2013|
a   |f   |12/06/2014|
b   |f   |12/04/2014|
c   |f   |12/09/2014|12/06/2014
d   |f   |12/08/2014|
```

(12/05/2013 = 5th of Dec)

```
UPDATE TAT_Test
SET DataNew = 
(select top 1 MAX(Data)
from TAT_Test 
where Col1 IN ('a','b')
) 
where Col1 IN ('c')
```

This is my attempt but not sure how to show inside the nested query that I'm looking for Col1=current record

Thanks!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Sql Server. Should have said this before. Thanks

Comment: Why is Datenew 12/04/2013 and not 12/08/2013 for Col2=x ? Unless there's an error in your sample the result does not make sense imo.

Comment: Why a top 1?  That can only be one max.

Answer (score 0):

If your data table was named "tbl" then try this:

```
update tbl
inner join (
    select max(data) as "new", col2 from tbl where col1 in ('a','b') group by col2
) as upd on (upd.col2=tbl.col2)
set tbl.DataNew=upd.new where tbl.col1='c';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you want:

```
UPDATE TAT_Test 
SET DataNew = 
  (SELECT MAX(Data) 
   FROM TAT_Test WHERE Col1 IN ('a','b') AND Col2 = t.Col2 ) 
FROM TAT_Test t
WHERE t.Col1 = 'c'
```

It gives the following output:

```
Col1 Col2 Data                    DataNew
---- ---- ----------------------- ----------
a    x    2013-12-05 01:00:00.000 NULL
b    x    2013-12-04 01:00:00.000 NULL
c    x    2013-12-09 01:00:00.000 2013-12-08   -- << this is not the row in 
b    x    2013-12-08 01:00:00.000 NULL         --    your sample, but it is
a    f    2014-12-06 01:00:00.000 NULL         --    the latest for the Col2 id
b    f    2014-12-04 01:00:00.000 NULL
c    f    2014-12-09 01:00:00.000 2014-12-06
d    f    2014-12-08 01:00:00.000 NULL
```